# Python in ArcGIS, CalculateField_management, updating with single value

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I have a float field which I want to simply update all values with 1. I can easily do this within the field calculator but I have started using python today, what is the syntax to simply update a field with the value 1. I'm stuck on the expression bit of the script:

> > > arcpy.CalculateField_management("ROCHDALE_TEST_NET","FRMEAS",??????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [ArcGIS help section](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000), you can see the necessary parameters and descriptions:

```
CalculateField_management (in_table, field, expression, {expression_type}, {code_block})
```

To translate this to your script;

```
import arcpy

file = r'C:\your\file.shp'

arcpy.CalculateField_management (file, "FRMEAS", "1")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking into it to much by doing =1 or "!FRMEAS! = 1"

Comment: @Aaron if it's a float field, do you have to put the 1 in quotes?

Comment: It is optional @ian